# Podio - Is it possible to assign an owner/creator to items?

Tags: podio

I have looked in the documentation regarding this and haven't been able to find anything. If it is possible, I would appreciate if you let me know where

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a creator to an item. The item_creator is the authenticated Podio entity that created the item.

You could add member fields to the app and assign anyone you want in that.